# Maintaining web services built with wsimport

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws

**Background**
I recently had to write a replacement for some existing web services. To do this I used jaxws with maven to run wsimport and generate the interface from the provided wsdl. This worked ok and was seamless for existing clients.

**Problem**
Most examples talk about writing a new web service but I now have to try and maintain these. My question is how best to add to or change these web services. I think these are my options:

- I could add some annotated methods to the generated code but this would then get out of sync with the imported wsdl and maven will wipe it out when I do a fresh build
- I could edit the wsdl I imported and re-run mvn generate-sources

Really the second one seems to be the only option but it's quite a big unwieldy wsdl to have to manually edit. To make things interesting a specification has already been written for the changes which gives example requests and responses which the new wsdl would have to match.

In summary then I would like to know if there's a better way than manually editing the wsdl or if I'm missing a tool that can help me. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually use a hybrid of generated code (schema->POJO) and generated artifacts (service->wsdl/schema).  We find it easiest to manage the DTOs using schemas, so we maintain them in the schemas and use xjc to spit out the POJOs.  like you mentioned, however, maintaining a WSDL can be a pain.  So, we manage the operation annotations on the the service implementation itself and allow JAX-WS to auto-generate the wsdl on its own.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for sharing. I would have to look into this some more. Might be tricky to automate the code generation in maven. I was trying to avoid manual steps in the build to try and keep things simple. Feels like a bit of a losing battle as soap is inherently complicated.

Comment: @BenThurley - we do all of this through public maven plugins.  the only "manual" parts are adding new types to the schemas and adding new operations to the service (which are kind of required).

Comment: I'm not sure this fits easily where we've already imported a wsdl but it's an interesting approach for new projects where we have carte blanche.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [XMLSpy WSDL editor](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/wsdl-editor.html)? It has a graphical editor for WSDL. There is a trial version for 30 days.

You can see a list of editors  in [XML Schema Editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_Editor#XML_Schema_Editors). This list not include to [Netbeans WSDL editor](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/xml_schema_editor_in_netbeans).